# How to get location from firebase and animate the car marker

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-location, android-fusedlocation

I have stored location into firebase as latitude and longitude. now i want to fetch the value of those and with help of that, car marker should be animated like car moving. so i did car marker animation. but it will show only for current location. i want for firebase location it should show animate.

Below method i am getting latitude longitude from firebase for that specific user

```
 private void getUserLocation() {


    loc.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Locations locations = dataSnapshot.getValue(Locations.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Each time onLocationChanged method called but it is retrieving current location only. i want firebase retrieved location should be changed

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location currentL) {

    mLastLocation = currentL;
    displayLocation();
}




public void displayLocation() {
    try {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            // Check Permissions Now
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LocationTracking.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {

            if (mLastLocation != null && mLastLocation.getLongitude() != 0.0 && mLastLocation.getLongitude() != 0.0) {

                if (mMap != null) {
                    addMarker(mMap, mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());

                }

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

now car is not at all moving.please guide me

Comment: You have to insert the value each time car changes the location. but according to your code it might be retrieving the same exact value again and again

Comment: could you please give me a code help

Comment: i haven't familier with onLocationChange code but if you provide me proper code when user change location and get his lat and longitude then i can help you in proper way

Comment: ya sure i will edit my question

Comment: i have edited my question. if need more clarify i will ready to modify @Ashish

Comment: does this work `mLastLocation.getLatitude()` properly ?

Comment: very sorry i forget to add this line.               mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206222/discussion-between-ashish-and-pitchai-mari).

Comment: its getting current location properly